# VBA - Iteration through dropdown/validation list and save generated sheets to one PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I am iterate through dropdown/validation list on given cell:

```
Sub SpitValues()
Dim dvCell As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Long

'Which cell has data validation
Set dvCell = Worksheets(3).Range("D4")
'Determine where validation comes from
Set inputRange = Worksheets(2).Range("C4:C5")

i = 1
'Begin our loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In inputRange
    dvCell = c.Value

    i = i + 1
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

On every iteration I need to save whole Worksheet(3) to variable and at the end I need to save all saved Worksheets to one PDF where every iteration data will be on separate page. So if I have for example five items in dropdown/validation list, there will be PDF with five pages. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Yes. It is possible.

Firstly, some cleanup. I have removed `i` as you don't use that variable. I have not turned off the screen updating because you want to extract each iteration. But, yes, turning off screen updating is usually a good performance measure.

The general algorithm to do this is to:

```
Identify where you are going to store the new pages
Make the change
Copy the page to the new store
loop
print
```

You had done some of this, now to complete the job.

```
Sub SpitValues()
    Dim dvCell As Range
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim NewWorkbook as workbook

    'Which cell has data validation
    Set dvCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Range("D4")
    'Determine where validation comes from
    Set inputRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("C4:C5")
    Set NewWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Add

    'Begin our loop
    For Each c In inputRange
        dvCell = c.Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Copy Before:=NewWorkbook.Sheets(NewWorkbook.Sheets.Count)  ' should insert this before the blank sheet at the end.
    Next c
'After this loop, print/save the new workbook. Change the file name to something suitable
    NewWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="Whatever", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Disclaimer: I have not had a chance to test this code yet.

Comment: This is excelent. My efforts were unnecessarily complicated. Thank you very much.